# Mandrill API user statistics

Tags: php, mandrill

I am using Mandrill service to send emails from
automated PHP script on my website.

I would like to know if there is
any possibility to get statistics (see attachment) from user's
dashboard such as reputation and free sends used this month
through API and if there is how I could get it.

I suppose user's reputation I can get at https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/users.JSON.html#method=info. However I can't find where I could get free sends used this month.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some simple math to find the minimum between the last 30 days and the current free quota of 12000 emails. An example in PHP (since you've tagged your question with PHP):

```
try {
    $mandrill = new Mandrill('YOUR_API_KEY');
    $results = $mandrill->users->info();
    $freeSendsThisMonth = min( 12000, $results['stats']['last_30_days']['sent'] );
} catch (Mandrill_Error $e) {
    // ...
}
```

Obviously this may be a "rougher" way to do things since months have a variance of +1/-2 days but it'll get you pretty close.

EDIT: Also realizing that last 30 days may not necessarily stop at the 1st day of the current billing month, or whatever billing cycle you have. You have your work cut out for you. Perhaps you could ask them nicely to include the stats at help (at) mandrill (dot) com?